# Post or pre note using \ref

Tags: hyperref

The figures I intend to include in my latex files are sometimes splitted into subfigures and labeled accordingly (e.g. have an (a), (b), etc marker), but still a single figure. This makes it easier for me to align them properly (labels (a) and (b) on the same height etc.). When I reference them in the text, I use something like `\ref{fig:my_face}(a)`. Using the `hyperref` package, the text linked includes only the figure number of course, not the (a) as well. Is there a way to include a post- or prenote like the `cite` command does (e.g. `\cite[p. 99]{myRef}` links the p.99 as well)?

The following code

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=red]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{fig.pdf}
\caption{
Some caption.
}
\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

\ref{fig:test}(a)

\end{document}
```

produces the output

[image]

I like to have the (a) also link to the image, so it should in appear in red too.

Comment: Doesn't `subfig` or `subcaption` package provide this feature already?

Comment: Yes, but I would have to provide multiple figures for that. I have my subfigures within a single figure.

Comment: It would be extremely helpful if you could provide a compilable example!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of a manual `\hyperref` and `\ref*`, wrapped inside a macro:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=red]{hyperref}

\newcommand{\myref}[2][]{\hyperref[#2]{\ref*{#2}#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}\quad
  \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-b}
  \caption{Some caption.}
  \label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

See Figure~\myref[(a)]{fig:test}.

\end{document}
```